# Server Root href and document root

Tags: php, xampp, document-root

I am new to PHP, and because of this, I am using XAMPP on OSX.  I am trying to provide the same `<a href="....">`s in production, as well as development.

I inherited a site that is all single level directory (i know, but it is not worth changing the plethora of code). Now I am trying to make a properly designed site.

So if I have a nav bar, with the following code:

```
  <li><a href="../services.php">Services</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Equipment<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="../equipment/equip1.php">Refrigerated Machines</a></li>
```

I was using `../` to get to the document root, and then set an absolute path.  On the production version it is working fine.  However on the Development version, it is going into the higher directories of XAMPP.   How do I set the server root for the server relative to site?

My folder systems is as follows

```
htdocs  # where ../ is going in development
  sites
    site1  # ../ should go here in this site's folder, not any other site's folder
    site2  # ../ should go here in this site's folder, not site1
  xampp
```

How do you account for multiple sites?  If I force the document root to `site1`, then how will site2 function properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can save you lots of trouble by working with the [base](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/base.html) html tag...

What I usually do is put something like this on my bootstrap file:

```
define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/site1'); // for development
// define('BASE_URL', 'http://somesite.com'); // for production
```

This in two separate files.

Then you'll have inside your `<head>` tag:

```
<base href="<?php echo BASE_URL ?>"/>
```

Now, all relative links in your pages will be relative to the path declared on your `<base>` tag.

### EDIT:

Oh, sorry, didn't pay attention to this possible confusion. Bootstrap is the name PHP programmers give to the initial configuration file. Usually, I put this in a `conf` directory inside my website root:

```
- mysite
--- conf
----- bootstrap.php
--- assets
----- js
----- css
--- src
--- test
-- index.php
```

My `bootstrap.php` file always define what is my application root:

```
define('APP_ROOT', dirname(__DIR__)); // since it's inside /conf/ dir.
```

This might solve your issues with relative directories within PHP.

Then, in my `index.php`, which is on my root, I have this at the very first line:

```
require 'conf/bootstrap.php';
```

I work with a single entrance point (the `index.php` file), so I just have to do this once. If you have multiple top level pages, you'll have to include this in every page.

If you keep the production bootstrap in your server and the development version on you localhost, you can forget about it.

Comment: When you say bootstrap file, do you mean twitter `bootstrap.js`, and if so where?  If not, please explain.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, son't you have to include the bootstrap file?  Since you have to do this, don't you have to set the absolute path of the bootstrap file in each page in order to get they dynamic root?

Answer (score 0):

Either you should setup virtual directory in apache or you can add html tag "base" to your head section in your template to setup base for all urls. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Actually if you using php to generate your template, you can generate absolute url inside php.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using HTML's [`base` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.4):

> This attribute specifies an absolute URI that acts as the base URI for resolving relative URIs.

You can use relative URIs now in your application and only need to (dynamically) change the `href` attribute on your `<base>` when porting to other sites.